# Is there a way to get groupby().cumcount() to ignore non-duplicate items in a dataframe, pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to get groupby().cumcount() to ignore non duplicate items in a dataframe, pandas?  I'm trying to identify and retain elements with duplicate ID values, but make it clear that this record has a duplicate value

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NameID': ['WS1', 'WS2', 'WS3', 'WS3', '01-1000', '01-1000', '01-1000', '01-1001'],
    'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'E'],
    'Value':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5', '5', '6']
})   

df['NameID'] = df['NameID'].str.cat(df.groupby('NameID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str), sep='_').str.replace("_0", "")
```

Input Dataframe

```
 NameID | Type | Value 
    - | - | - 
    WS1 | A | 1
    WS2 | B | 2
    WS3 | C1 | 3
    WS3 | C2 | 4
    01-1000 | D1 | 5
    01-1000 | D1 | 5
    01-1000 | D1 |5
    01-1001 | E | 6
```

Dataframe with result I want

```
 NameID | Type | Value 
    - | - | - 
    WS1 | A | 1
    WS2 | B | 2
    WS3_1 | C1 | 3
    WS3_2 | C2 | 4
    01-1000_1 | D1 | 5
    01-1000_2 | D1 | 5
    01-1000_3 | D1 |5
    01-1001 | E | 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an `np.where`:

```
df['NameID'] = np.where(df['NameID'].duplicated(keep=False),
                        df['NameID'].str.cat(df.groupby('NameID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str), sep='_'),
                        df['NameID'])
```

Output:

```
      NameID Type Value
0        WS1    A     1
1        WS2    B     2
2      WS3_1   C1     3
3      WS3_2   C2     4
4  01-1000_1   D1     5
5  01-1000_2   D1     5
6  01-1000_3   D1     5
7    01-1001    E     6
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you achieve this by defining a short mask, like this :

```py
mask = ~df.index.isin(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['NameID'], keep=False).index)
```

- drop_duplicates(...) : filters out duplicated `NameID`
- df.index.isin(...) : checks if df index values are in reduced df (without duplicates)
- operator `~` : inverts boolean logic to get rows without unique `NameID`

**Complete script**

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'NameID': ['WS1', 'WS2', 'WS3', 'WS3', '01-1000', '01-1000', '01-1000', '01-1001'],
    'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D1', 'D1', 'E'],
    'Value':['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5', '5', '6']
}) 

mask = ~df.index.isin(df.drop_duplicates(subset=['NameID'], keep=False).index)

r = df[mask]['NameID'].str.cat(df.groupby('NameID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str), sep='_')

df.loc[r.index, 'NameID']=r

print(df)
```

**Result**

```py
      NameID Type Value
0        WS1    A     1
1        WS2    B     2
2      WS3_1   C1     3
3      WS3_2   C2     4
4  01-1000_1   D1     5
5  01-1000_2   D1     5
6  01-1000_3   D1     5
7    01-1001    E     6
```